# How can I tag along on an Atlantic crossing?

Tags: oceanic, ferry-flight

I'm a private pilot based in the US and interested in tagging along on a North Atlantic crossing. I have too little experience to dare to attempt it myself, but I'd love to experience it. Does anyone know if there is a way of making that happen? E.g. are there pilots who take guests along? Or are there legal or insurance impediments?
Many thanks for any information!

Comment: [Just go to the airport and hold out your thumb and hope things work out.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W9Uf-ynoDUE)

Answer (score 2):

Contact companies that do ferry/delivery services.  You'd probably have to pay for your own immersion suit, IF someone was willing to let you come along.  Yes insurance will also probably be an issue.